# Complex Sumproduct formula

Tags: excel

Please could someone help me work out the sumproduct equation for something a little tricky.

Here is what I am trying to acheive.
Look in column B:B of sheet Postings, where it matches cell A3 = Tier 1, then   sumproduct Postings! Column K:K, M:M

I have tried this.

```
IF(SUMIF(Postings!B:B,Sheet1!A3)<>0,Postings!$K$3:$K$201,Postings!$M$3:$M$201)
```

Comment: This question would benefit highly from sample data with expected results. Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want this:

`=SUMPRODUCT((Postings!$B$3:$B$201=Sheet1!A3)+0,Postings!$K$3:$K$201,Postings!$M$3:$M$201)`

That will multiply columns K and M only for rows where the column B criterion is met, and sum the results, is that what you need?